# How to control the quality of selenium screenshots

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, screenshot

I've got an issue with selenium taking screenshots that are large. For example, a page that has many images it will capture that screenshot at 2MB. is there a way to control the quality of the screenshots to reduce the file size. Like if i lower the quality of the screenshot then the file size will reduce as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there isn't any control over this.  I suppose you could use an image-processing library to reprocess it in your test script, but Selenium won't help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I used to save screenshots as .png which caused the file to be of bigger size. I changed it to .jpg and it got reduced.

Answer (score -1):

With C# just use this method the change quality from .png to .jpeg and reduce quality/size:

```
System.Drawing.ImageFormat.Jpeg
```